# Asp.NET core error after publish code to ubuntu linux, developed on windows

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, coreclr

Hoping you can help me with this strange error. I've developed a very simple ASP.NET Core web application on windows 10 using visual studio code. I've run **`dotnet publish`** command and tried running the application from under the "publish" folder, which was created. I used the command **`dotnet Project.dll`**. It worked and I was able to browse localhost on port 5000 to view the application.

I then zipped the content of the "publish" folder and copied to a linux VM running Ubuntu 16.04, but I've received the following strange error on the command line when I try to execute the application using: **`dotnet Project.dll`**. I was using ssh to remote to linux vm and execute the command above.

### ERROR MESSAGE SEEN ON COMMAND LINE:

Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'System.Net.NetworkInformation', version: '4.1.0', path: 'runtimes/linux/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll'

---

I used the following link to install .net core on the vm: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

When I do `dotnet --version` on windows I see: **1.0.0-preview2-003121**
When I do `dotnet --verison` on Ubuntu I see: **1.0.0-preview2-003131**

Any help to resolve the above error would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the project.json file:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",    
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration":"1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "MailKit": "1.8.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "web.config", 
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Company.Website"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try instead publish folder copy to VM with Ubuntu, project folder and run command from main folder of project. Try follow this tutorial http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have created an portable app, but did not installed .NET Core runtime on Linux. When you create a portable app, you have to install the runtime.

If you create a self-contained application, then you don't need to install the runtime.

Basically when you use

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
}
```

It's platform/runtime dependent and you need a runtime installed but have smaller deployment file size.

If you remove the `"type": "platform"`, then its a self-contained and you need additionally add

```
 "runtimes": {
   "win10-x64": {},
   "osx.10.10-x64": {}
 }
```

to your project.json with **all** platforms you want to be able to deploy. With the above you can't run it on Linux.

After that you can `dotnet build/publish` to build/bundle/publish it. You will get one folder per platform above.

Source: http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

Comment: It doesn't look like that's the issue here, if .Net Core wasn't installed, `dotnet --version` wouldn't work and `dotnet Project.dll` wouldn't talk about missing assemblies.

Comment: You have to have the same version installed. In windows you can look in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` to see which versions are installed. 1 version per folder. On windows you should only have `1.0.0` and on Ubuntu you should have `1.0.1` based on your `dotnet --version` output

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on [GitHub for .NET](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3262). I added these lines to the project.json dependencies:

```
"runtime.linux.System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0-beta-*",
"runtime.unix.System.Net.Security": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
```

This fixed my Ubuntu publishing problem. I did not have any Windows problems continuing to debug in IIS Express or Visual Studio with these additional dependencies.